# Creating multilanguage homepage translating

Tags: php

Okay, so i got class file, in which i got function -

```
var $text;                     

public function languages()
{
  if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != '')
  {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
  }
  switch($_SESSION['lang'])
  {
    case 'en_EN': require_once('language/lang.eng.php');break;
    case 'lv_LV': require_once('language/lang.lv.php');break;
    case 'ru_RU': require_once('language/lang.ru.php');break;
    default: require_once('language/lang.eng.php');
  }
  $this->text = $text;
}

public function translate($txt)
{
  if(isset($this->text[$txt]))
  {
    return $this->text[$txt];
  }
}
```

If i am translating via index.php like this - > `echo $index->translate('search');` it translates ok, but if i am translating something in class file for example -

```
if ($country_rows > 0)
{
  $_SESSION['country'] = $_GET['country'];
}
else
{                                                      
  $_SESSION['country'] = $this->translate('all_countries');
}
}
if ($_SESSION['country'] == '')
{ 
  $_SESSION['country'] = $this->translate('all_countries');
}
```

it doesn't show up.
In index.php header i got included -

```
require_once('class.index.php');
$index = new index;
$index->get_country();
$index->languages();
```

What could be the problem, and how can i fix it, so i can translate everything inside class file too? will appreciate your help!

Comment: We are only seeing bits and pieces here.  Can you break down the problem anymore?

Comment: well, as i said, in class file $this->translate('smth_here'); is not working, it won't just show up anything, but in index.php where i define class index; $index->translate('smth_here'); it will translate just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st guess:
no session started?

```
session_start();
```

2nd guess:
assuming that you use `$this->translate()` in another class, you should initiate the object first, in the following example I pass translate class to `var $index;`

```
<?
include_once('class.index.php');
class myClass {
  var $index;

  public function __construct() {
    $index = new index();
    $index->get_country();
    $index->languages();
    $this->index = $index;
  }

  public function yourFunction() {
    echo $this->index->translate('all_countries');
    print_r($this->index);
  }
}
?>
```